# What's the inductive hypothesis here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

This question pertains to the proof mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1147308/880839). What is the inductive hypothesis here? As I can decipher it, it seems like:

> If $i$ is the number of terms in 2-cycle identity permutations and $i<r$ then $i$ is even.

Can someone verify this? Or if wrong mention the correct hypothesis.

Comment: It says if the identity permutation is written as a product of $r$ transpositions, then $r$ is even. There is no such thing as a two cycle identity permutation because the identity leaves everything fixed and a transposition does not.

Comment: $\Large\color{\green}{\checkmark}$ Your guess is correct.

Comment: @JohnDouma So you are implying that (12)(12) is not an identity permutation? The question never mentioned the cycles to be disjoint.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @ShyamTripathi No. That would be two transpositions which is an even number of them. I am saying $(12)$ or any other single transposition is not the identity. What you wrote are two $2$-cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of what is sometimes called *strong induction*. The hypothesis of strong induction is that the theorem is true for all values less than $r$. One place you see the strong induction hypothesis used is where it says "By induction, $r-2$ is even; hence, $r$ must be even." Your statement does, indeed, appear to be identical to the strong induction hypothesis.